# Hierarchy Problem and SUSY: Quantum Loop Corrections

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, supersymmetry, interactions, fine-tuning

One of the reasons SUSY was developed in the 1970s is to solve the mass hierarchy problem with the Higgs, according to which the mass of the Higgs is "unnatural" (cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356 chapter 1 for a more thorough introduction).

Assuming that the masses of the sleptons and squarks are exactly the same as the leptons and quarks, the quantum loop corrections to the Higgs mass would exactly cancel.

In Figure 1.1 of the above mentioned paper, we can find the following two diagrams:[image]

$f$ describes a Dirac fermion and $S$ a scalar. But why does the loop for the scalar look so different than for the Dirac fermion? So why is the loop with the scalar **above** the Higgs line and not "in between"? I guess this has a physical meaning?

**Follow-up**: Judging from the answer, drawing the loop above the Higgs line does indeed have a meaning. But then, in Fig. 18.3 of Mark Thomson's book *Modern Particle Physics* one can find a quantum loop correction to the Higgs boson mass with the particle in the loop being the Higgs boson.

Now I am confused why the loop is "in between" the Higgs bosons again, even though the Higgs is a scalar particle...

Answer (score 2):

Drawing the diagrams this way reflects the fact that the Higgs interacts with fermions via $\phi \bar{f} f$ but interacts with scalars via $\phi^2 S S^*$. This is plausible because in $d = 4$, four scalars have the same engineering dimension as one scalar and two fermions. Moreover, the mass term for a fermion is $m^2 S S^*$ for a scalar whereas it is $m f \bar{f}$ for a fermion. If $f$ and $S$ are to have the same mass, we need an extra power of the Higgs for the latter since the mass comes from expanding around $\phi = v + H$.

Note that models like this generically lead to *both* types of loops for scalars. In particular, the Higgs potential itself becomes
\begin{align}
V &= \lambda(\phi^2 - v^2)^2 \\
&= \lambda(4v^2 H^2 + 4v H^3 + H^4).
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit to my question to ask a follow-up question.

Comment: That should just come from the Mexican hat potential.